# Neo4j very slow for graph import

Tags: performance, graph, neo4j, load

I'm using neo4j to load a graph . It is a csv file of 11 million rows 
and it is taking a long time for loading 
2 hours have passed yet the graph is not finished loading yet 
Is it normal ? 
My laptop  is an i7  2.4Ghs and 8g RAM

The sample data:

```
 protein1   protein2    combined_score
    9615.ENSCAFP00000000001 9615.ENSCAFP00000014827 151
    9615.ENSCAFP00000000001 9615.ENSCAFP00000026847 802
    9615.ENSCAFP00000000001 9615.ENSCAFP00000015235 900
    9615.ENSCAFP00000000001 9615.ENSCAFP00000007210 261
    9615.ENSCAFP00000000001 9615.ENSCAFP00000025394 248
    9615.ENSCAFP00000000001 9615.ENSCAFP00000038575 900
    9615.ENSCAFP00000000001 9615.ENSCAFP00000011457 177
    9615.ENSCAFP00000000001 9615.ENSCAFP00000002193 503
    9615.ENSCAFP00000000001 9615.ENSCAFP00000042321 900
    9615.ENSCAFP00000000001 9615.ENSCAFP00000011541 207
    9615.ENSCAFP00000000001 9615.ENSCAFP00000038517 183
    9615.ENSCAFP00000000001 9615.ENSCAFP00000003009 151
```

Query

```
    CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:Node) ASSERT n.NodeID IS UNIQUE;
    USING PERIODIC COMMIT
    LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///linksdog.csv'
    AS line

    MERGE (n1:Node {NodeID: line.protein1})
    MERGE (n2:Node {NodeID: line.protein2})

MERGE (n1)-[:ACTING_WITH {Score: TOFLOAT(line.combined_score)}]->(n2);
```

Comment: Can you give a sample of the data you're loading and how you're loading it? Can you also provide relevant indexes and constraints being used? Also, are you using PERIODIC COMMIT during csv import?

Comment: @InverseFalcon i edited the question

Comment: You do not set a value on your periodic commit. Maybe the default is not a good value for your import.

I would advise to do that in several passes.
First LOAD CSV to create the proteins
Second, you MATCH proteins, then create the relation

This is how I solved a very slow import.

I assume you use the latest version of neo4j

Comment: @JeromeB yes I'm using the lastest version. What if I do not use periodic commit at all ?

Comment: Would be worse I guess. Just do two LOAD CSV. Or even 3.
LOAD + CREATE protein1
LOAD + MERGE protein2
LOAD + 2xMATCH + CREATE relation

Comment: I think its just MERGE on an empty base that needs improvement on the db side.